# json single value condition in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL database field that contains JSON type data stored.

```
-----------------------------
id |     tags              |
-----------------------------
1  |    ['cat','dog']      |
2  | ['lion','cat','dog']  |
```

I want to select from this table by passing where condition as `cat` and get all the JSON fields. How would I do this?

Comment: Use `Like` operator. Refer http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  5.7 has native support for JSON.

Comment: its not possible with sql query i think

Answer (score 0):

Use the JSON_EXTRACT function as of MySQL 5.7.8.  Extract from 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-paths

```
A JSON path expression selects a value within a JSON document.

Path expressions are useful with functions that extract parts of or modify a JSON document, to specify where within that document to operate. For example, the following query extracts from a JSON document the value of the member with the name key:

mysql> SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"id": 14, "name": "Aztalan"}', '$.name');
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| JSON_EXTRACT('{"id": 14, "name": "Aztalan"}', '$.name') |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| "Aztalan"                                               |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Note in the example they are inline creatinng a JSON object so for you
:'{"id": 14, "name": "Aztalan"}' would actually be your column value.

Comment: but i store my json as only values which was like shown above in question `['cat','dog']`

Answer (score 0):

JSON manipulation in MySQL is slow. I suggest that you use REGEXP.

```
// get all rows having "cat" value
select * from animals_tbl
where tags regexp 'cat';

// get all rows based on multiple filters
select * from animals_tbl
where tags regexp 'lion|cat';
```